# Jplayer how to display buffering text

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I want to be able to control showing/hiding the word "buffering..." on the progress bar on JPlayer.

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').bind($.jPlayer.event.canplay, function(event) {
    if (event.jPlayer.status.paused === true){
        alert('loading');
    } else {
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem at all that english is not your native language, but a bigger problem that you came empty handed - no code, nothing. [What have you actually tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `$('#jquery_jplayer_1').bind($.jPlayer.event.canplay, function(event) {
        if (event.jPlayer.status.paused === true){
            alert('loading');
        } else {
            
        }
    });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jplayer how to display “buffering” text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123390/jplayer-how-to-display-buffering-text)